# firebase sdk にてアプリの version を指定して通知を送ることは可能でしょうか

Tags: go, firebase

firebase のコンソール画面から通知を作成するときにアプリのバージョンを指定できることは知っているのですが、現在 go でサーバーを書いていて、その際sdkを使用して fcm 経由で通知を行なっています。

sdkにて app version を指定したいのですが、ドキュメントに記載が見つからないので、もし知っていらっしゃる方がいたら教えていただきたいです

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages?hl=ja#ApnsConfig